# Jenkins --> JUnit throwing OutOfMemoryError PermGen on Linux

Tags: linux, ant, junit, jenkins

I am running around thousands(10K) of Junit using Jenkins on Linux during build time, but it is throwing OutOfMemoryError.

```
/builds/build.xml:113: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:634)
    at
```

Following JVM configuration is set for JUnit for that job on configure --> "invoke ant" --> advance

```
Xms512m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m
```

Even after increasing the PermGen and HeapSize till 3072m, it is failing on the same test.

Am I doing the configure on wrong place? 
Is Jenkins restricting me to increase invoke ant configuration beyond certain limit? 
Is Jenkins configuration also need to increase to effect the JUnit ant configuration? If yes, can someone suggest how to increase Jenkins heap and PermGen configuration?

Comment: I hope `-` (minus) sign that is missing before Xms in your line above is just a typo.

Comment: Your stack trace is not complete. Is it from jenkins or ant? The Permgen error is not related to number of tests. It is typically related to number of classes you load to JVM. So if you many jars in your ant or many plugins in jenkins... it can come either tools.

Answer (score 1):

When it's a `PermGen space` error, using `Xms` & `Xmx` parameter will not affect the error. Instead of setting up the options in `Build > Invoke Ant > Advanced... > Java Options`, i suggest you add these options to the Jenkins startup script.

```
-XX:PermSize=512m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m
```

Try increasing `MaxPermSize` value, if needed.

Comment: @Mukul: Did you try the suggestion?